# Conditional Independence over evidences

Tags: conditional-probability, topic-models

Suppose that we have different evidences $e_1, e_2, \ldots$, and we know the conditional probability of event $t$ over each of them, say $P(t|e_i)$.

Now I have a set of observed evidences $e_i$, and want to know the probability of $t$ happening. Does it make sense to use $P(t|e_1) + P(t|e_2)$? Or is there any conditional independence like $P(t|e_1,e_2) = P(t|e_1)\cdot P(t|e_2)$?

Comment: You must define your terms! What do "evidence" mean for you? Is it an observed event (looks so from your formulas). In such case, we really need to know if those events are independent or not, for instance.

Comment: The evidences are words in documents and $t is a specific topic from a topic set (in topic modeling domain). I have the distribution probability of topics per word, and I would like to determine the topic when a subset of words is observed.